# Missing Visual Studio Web Application publish targets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am missing the usual publish targets when publishing my c# web application. The usual "Import" and "Custom" options are missing when I go to publish, as well as the "Manage Profiles" drop down that has the option to create a new profile.

Here is the screen I am presented with.

[image: Missing Publish Targets]

The buttons on the left hand side are "greyed out"

Here is another screen from a colleague that has the missing options

[image: Correct Publish Targets]

I have tried a full reinstall of Visual Studio 2015 update 1 with no success. I have also tried creating a fresh ASP.NET Web application project in a new solution resulting with the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried my solutions? What's your development in this question so far?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end this ended up being a corrupt publish profile file in the `Properties/PublishProfiles/xxxx.pubxml` within the project.

Answer (score 1):

There are multipy options for this behavior:

- Issue with the **Web Deploy** Tool

  Try to reinstall the current [Web Deploy 3.5](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) Tool
- Depending on the exact **Version of your Visual Studio** and **your Operating System**

  There are known issues about specific OS/Visual Studio combinations.
- **Missing Web Developer Tools** at Installation

  Select the `Web Developer Tools` Option at installation

  [image: Option for installation]

Comment: Personally i think it's a Web Deploy Tool issue, since Azure SDK is working.